Geometries not being parsed using WMSGetFeatureInfo when geometry is GeometryCollection
I am using OpenLayers to query a WMS layer using WMSGetFeatureInfo.
When querying layers, I want to extract the geometry. This works fine except when the returned geometry is a GeometryCollection. In those instances, no geometry seems ot get parsed by the readFeatures function of WMSGetFeatureInfo.
Here is the code that does that actual retrieval (assuming URL is a valid WMS GetFeatureInfo request requesting GML)
fetch(url)
      .then((response) => response.text())
      .then((data) => {
        const features = new WMSGetFeatureInfo().readFeatures(data);
        features.forEach((feature) => {
          console.log(feature.getGeometry());
        });
        document.getElementById(
          'info',
        ).innerHTML = `Total features: ${features.length}`;
      });
  }

Working example (warning, example uses a real layer from our production GeoServer. It may only be accessible from UK based IP addresses due to firewall restrictions, if anyone else has a suitable layer with GeometryCollections in, please replace it) -
https://codesandbox.io/p/sandbox/getfeatureinfo-tile-forked-2znl2q?workspaceId=1f8eee06-aaeb-4f33-bf0a-2fd3eb7b6297 - To try this, click the polygon in the middle of the map (circled in green in the screenshot below). This will return undefined in the console. Then click the polygon circled in blue in the screenshot below. This will return some geometries.

On the line console.log(feature.getGeometry()) you get the geometry if its a line, polygon, point etc., but undefined if its a geometry collection.
Is this a limitation or bug of OpenLayers, or something I am doing wrong?

It looks like the Open:Layers GML parser does not support GeometryCollection.

@Mike that was the conclusion I was coming to, I just wanted to make sure I wasn't missing anything obvious. Unless someone comes up with something tomorrow, I'll open a bug in the OpenLayers repo.

Looks like there is a semi-related issue already open here - https://github.com/openlayers/openlayers/issues/4220
